# How to include sidekick and parsys in a page (AEM)

Tags: aem

I have created a simple page and trying to include sidekick and parsys in that page. I have included **init.jsp** and parsys in my code. But when I load a page it does not show up. Please help me with this. Thank you.

```
<cq:include script="/libs/wcm/core/components/init/init.jsp"/>
<cq:include path="par" resourceType="libs/foundation/components/parsys" />
```

Comment: You neef global.jsp as well for the cq:include tag to work

Answer (score 0):

the code provided for including parsys wont work .
correct one is:

```
<cq:include path="par" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys"/>
```

Comment: <cq:include path="par" resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys"/>

Comment: Edit that into your question.